# Unhandled Exception in Unity3D Windows Store Project

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, windows-store-apps, unity-game-engine

I created a Unity3D project and built it as Windows Store C# XAML app. Things didn't work right. So I created a new empty project. I aligned my view with the view of the Main Camera and created a cube at its default position so that it can be seen in the Game View. I again built this project as Windows Store C# XAML adding the only Scene in build. I configured the target platform as x86 in Solution Configuration Properties after the solution was created.. When I tried to deploy it on Local Machine (I don't have any other tablet), I get the same problems as earlier.

It loads up the splash screen of Unity3D. Then it shows error of unhandled exception. So I commented that line out and continued but that gave me another exception. I did the same thing again and more and more unhandled exceptions came up in the following order:

```
36: appCallbacks = new AppCallbacks(false);    //FileNotFoundException
59: appCallbacks.SetBridge(_bridge);           //NullReferenceException
61: appCallbacks.SetSwapChainBackgroundPanel(mainPage.GetSwapChainBackgroundPanel());     //NullReferenceException
64: appCallbacks.SetCoreWindowEvents(Window.Current.CoreWindow);   //NullReferenceException
66: appCallbacks.InitializeD3DXAML();    //NullReferenceException
```

All these exceptions occurred in file App.xaml.cs.
In each exception first I have mentioned the line no. of the statement, then the statement and then the exception that occurred.

After commenting all the above statements, the app runs successfully but nothing shows up (only a black screen). Also when I try to browse the solution folder, I do not recognise anything related to my Unity3D project (when I had created a full project in Unity3D). I can see noticeably the splash screen and logo images in Assets folder and Unity3D references in solution explorer. There were no assets, scripts etc. there in the solution folder.

I am using Unity3D 4.2 and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

I took screenshots of my steps and made a zip out of it. I have uploaded it on dropbox. Here's the link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/88nod5pfxxgscra/Unity.zip

Comment: Ehm, why are you starting a new account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/2119964/temp-id And why ask a question you already asked on that account before?

Comment: I have lost the access to the original email id I used previously. So I am changing my email id.

Comment: This the first time it is taking too long to get a solution on SO.

Comment: So you have a new account because you couldn't access the old one. Yet you were able to delete the duplicate question from the old one? Seems strange. But if anything you might want to merge with your old account so you can have your rep and questions back. It would be a shame to see some of them go unaccepted if they have a correct answer for example. See this for instructions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist

Comment: I think I had first deleted it. Still I can log in to my earlier SO account but not the email id associated with it. So I want to change my email id completely.

Comment: That is no problem. You can add additional identities to your account. Go to your account page, click on "my logins" and add additional/new logins to your existing account. Then you can remove the old one, if you wish.